# Mathematical error in physics restitution formula

Tags: actionscript-3, math, physics

I admit it. I'm a mathematical imbecile. should I be attempting this at home? Probably not without serious injury. Anyway. Anyone that has a bit of experience in games and physics who can review this code and provide insight into why there is a built in "loss" in velocity in prototype would be hugely admired.

the concept: the actor falls from the sky, at some point intersects a boundary (trampoline.y) after which gravity (in this example a value of 1.6) stops operating and a restitution factor (in this case a value of -6) takes over.

right now I'm trying to create a zero-sum situation where you have the same velocity coming out of the trampoline "bounce" (hero.y >= trampoline.y) as you did going in. That's just not the case as the traces reveal.

I've tried about five different approaches and this is the latest, given the insight that at any given "tic" of my game timer (33 ms) we may have passed the boundary of the trampoline and thus the acceleration rules will have changed. I really thought I had it, but the results show a decrease in velocity after each bounce, which is not what I expected.

I submit the following code to your wizened review:

```
var newV:Number;
if (hero.y < trampoline.y) { newV = hero.velocityY + gravityAccelerationInPixels }
else { newV = hero.velocityY + TrampolineActor.SPRING_ACCELERATION }

var newY:Number = hero.y + newV;
trace("Coming in: y=" + hero.y + " oldVelocity=" + hero.velocityY + " newVelocity=" + newV + " Change in V: " + (newV - hero.velocityY) + ". Testing for newY=" + newY);

if ((hero.y < trampoline.y && newY < trampoline.y) || (hero.y >= trampoline.y && newY >= trampoline.y)) {
    hero.y = newY;
    hero.velocityY = newV;
} else {
    trace("SPLIT");

    var percent:Number = (trampoline.y - hero.y) / newV; trace("Percent: " + percent);
    var newVV:Number;
    if (hero.y < trampoline.y) {
        // going down!
        newVV = hero.velocityY + percent * gravityAccelerationInPixels; trace("New velocity before split: " + hero.velocityY + " Change in V: " + (newVV - hero.velocityY));
        newVV += (1 - percent) * TrampolineActor.SPRING_ACCELERATION; trace("Percent after split: " + (1 - percent) + " Change in V: " + (newVV - hero.velocityY));
    } else {
        // movin on up!
        newVV = hero.velocityY + percent * TrampolineActor.SPRING_ACCELERATION; trace("New velocity before split: " + hero.velocityY + " Change in V: " + (newVV - hero.velocityY));
        newVV += (1 - percent) * gravityAccelerationInPixels; trace("Percent after split: " + (1 - percent) + " Change in V: " + (newVV - hero.velocityY));
    }
    trace("New velocity: " + newVV + " Change in V: " + (newVV - hero.velocityY));

    hero.velocityY = newVV;

    hero.y += hero.velocityY;
}
```

Additional INFO:
Screen origin is top-left, so y-- = higher up
My tic is currently set to 33 ms
gravityAccelerationInPixels is currently 1.62 (reasonably arbitrary)
SPRING_ACCELERATION is arbitrarily 6, but I hope to tweak that number to control how far below the trampoline the character can go during the deceleration/absorption cycle.

For now I'm hoping to have a solution where the velocity on the tic after the character leaves contact with the trampoline is the same (but negative) of the velocity just prior to going in. Heck I've even tried storing and retrieving the entry position and velocity, but that just looks like a hiccup.

Comment: Could it be that you're not taking into account the acceleration that occurs during the tick where the hero crosses the trampoline boundary? Your code seems to assume that whenever the hero goes below the trampoline that the previous tick he was exactly *on* the trampoline. When this is not the case, I think you lose some velocity.

Comment: thanks Gabe! I could be wrong, but that is exactly what my code is trying to solve. The whole bottom part is my realization that at the tic, the next move will cross the boundary. So I look at the velocity UP TO the boundary, as a percentage of the tic, then add the remaining change in velocity after the boundary. That whole "percent" business is the my attempt to take into account WHERE (between the last tic and this one) the boundary crossing occurs, and then to assign a percentage to it so I can calculate a more realistic vector.

Comment: Three questions: 1) Does `y` increase upward or downward, 2) do you mind if your trampoline behaves in an unphysical way, like upward gravity rather than an elastic, 3) do you want do know where your code goes wrong, or a working solution, or both?

Comment: Right on Beta! Thanks for your interest. 1) as y value decreases, altitude on screen goes UP (screen origin is top-left corner)  2) it's a game so I don't care what we have to do - I've already fudged it with a constant (6) to simulate absorption and restitution 3) I'm much more interested in figuring out where I go wrong. I would love to learn from this because I've been fighting with this code for a week now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might also want to adjust the delta velocity (from acceleration) and displacement (from velocity) to reflect the actual amount of milliseconds elapsed between the time you finished rendering the last frame, and the time you started rendering the current frame. This will help keep things looking smooth when the interval between frames is not exactly 33ms (Flash's enter frame event is notoriously inexact timing-wise, but some frames are bound to take longer to update than others anyway). This would require keeping track of velocity and acceleration in meters (or feet, or whatever) per second

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are some debugging techniques for this type of simulation:

- First: Make sure you know what units every single one of your variables and constants is in. For example, if `hero.y` is a distance in *pixels*, then since it is adjusted by `hero.y + newV`, it must be the case that `newV` is also in *pixels*; except that it is supposed to be a speed (distance per time), so it must actually be `pixels per frame` (where the time step is implicit because you're doing this once per frame).

  For the next debugging steps, it would be better to make sure all your values are expressed in “per second” rather than “per frame”; to do this, introduce a value equal to your timestep in seconds per frame. Then you have `hero.y + newV * timestep` and similarly `newV = hero.velocityY + gravityAccelerationInPixelsPerSecondSquared * timestep`.

  It's OK to compute `gravityAccelerationInPixelsPerSecondSquared * timestep` as a constant in itself, but make sure that all your hardcoded values do not depend on your timestep, so that you can easily:
- Try decreasing your timestep by some factor *k*. If doing this reduces your error, then your problem is because your discrete timestep calculations are not matching the perfect integral-over-time answer. If this does not reduce your error, then your simulation is consistent but in some sense “unphysical”.
- Try computing the total energy of your system. That is, sum

  - the kinetic energy of any moving bodies, 1/2·*m·v*² (*m* = mass, *v* = velocity)
  - the potential energy of any falling bodies, *m·g·h* (*g* = gravitational acceleration constant, *h* = height above an arbitrary reference point)
  - the potential energy of any springs, 1/2·*k·d*² (*k* = spring constant, hopefully equal to your "restitution factor" (but positive), *d* = distance displaced from relaxed state)

  If you let *h* = `hero.y - trampoline.y`, then for your particular system you have

  *E* = 1/2·*m·v*² + *m·g*·max(*h*, 0) + 1/2·*k*·(min(*h*, 0))²

  (From my reading of your code, gravity is not applied while the character is on the trampoline; if it is, change max(*h*, 0) to just *h*.)

  Make sure you do this in consistent dimensions (you can't add *pixels per second* to *pixels*) and units (you can't add *pixels per second* to *pixels per frame* or to *inches per second*). Don't forget that squaring squares the units too.

  For your stated goal — the character bouncing up with the same velocity — you have a *frictionless* system, and so the system's energy should be identical before, during, and after the bounce. If the energy changes, then note *when* it changes. For example:

  - If it changes while the character is falling, then your simulation of that case, constant acceleration, is incorrect. **A common mistake (which it looks like you've made in your code) is to forget the third term of the formula for position [under constant acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics#Kinematics_of_constant_acceleration):** `newPos = pos + velocity * timestep + 1/2 * acceleration * timestep^2`, where the *acceleration* is gravity. (It is also important that you update the position *before* you update the velocity, so that you are not using "tomorrow's" velocity with "yesterday's" position in the position calculation.) Try simulating bouncing on a hard surface instead of the trampoline to simplify the situation.
  - If it changes exactly when the character touches or leaves the trampoline, your `percent` computation is not achieving its goal.

Comment: Could my issues have to do with using the (fallacious) Euler integration? http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/

Comment: @Tom Auger: That's what the bolded part of my answer is about — getting the integration right. For this simple problem, you *can* use a fancier numerical integration technique, but my approach as described is to fix up your formulas to be the exact closed-form versions (applied over a small time interval repeatedly so that you have animation rather than an end-point answer) instead.